# Adding input directly to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am trying to shorten my code by putting input directly into a list. This is my code:

```
n = input('Enter: ')
lista = [n[i] for i in range(len(n))]
```

I am trying to put this in one line. I tried couple of variations but none of them worked. Is this even possible to do in python ?

Comment: It's possible, but I would not recommend it since you usually want to check for input correctness before using it.

Comment: Please don't tag a question with `input` in the code as python 2.7 AND 3.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> lista = list(input("Enter: "))
Enter: hello
>>> lista
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Or, if you insist that you absolutely must use a list comprehension for some reason,

```
>>> lista = (lambda n: [n[i] for i in range(len(n))])(input("Enter: "))
Enter: hello
>>> lista
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Or, if all you actually wanted was to put the input into a list as a single element:

```
>>> lista = [input("Enter: ")]
Enter: hello
>>> lista
['hello']
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't even *need* to use a comprehension with `range(len(n))` here since you're just creating a list out of each element in the string returned from `input`.

A one-line equivalent is simply using:

```
lista = list(input('Enter: '))
```

or, alternatively, for Python `>=` 3.5:

```
lista = [*input('Enter: ')]
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
letters = [letter for letter in input('Enter: ')]
```

Try it out:

```
>>> letters = [letter for letter in input('Enter: ')]
Enter: hello
>>> letters
['h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o']
```

Or if you enter a sentence and want individual words, use `input('Enter: ').split()`.

Answer (score 0):

Another useful way to parsing arguments from the command line to the python script is the package `argparse`.

The following example shows you how to parse arguments in a list:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse Arguments')
parser.add_argument('--to-list', nargs='+', help='read Arguments as a list')
args = parser.parse_args()

list = args.to-list
```

The usage would be:

```
python parseArguments.py --to-list Hello World !

>>> list
['Hello','World', '!']
```